# How to get prediction value for serving mlflow bert model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, mlflow

Got Error messing for predicting after serving the model. I want my output in pytorch tensor.

I am using bert for classification in pytorch and mlflow for model tracking and model serving.
I have written a code after serving the model.

```
import requests

sentence = text
inputs = tokenizer(sentence, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=MAX_LEN, return_tensors="pt")

ids = inputs["input_ids"]
mask = inputs["attention_mask"]

inference_request = {
          "instances": [ids, mask]
}

endpoint = "http://localhost:1234/invocations"
response = requests.post(endpoint, json=inference_request)
print(response.json())
```

My model architecture looks like this:

```
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', 
                                                   num_labels=len(id2label),
                                                   id2label=id2label,
                                                   label2id=label2id)
```

Command I run for serving the model :

```
mlflow models serve --model-uri models:/ner-classifier/Production -p 1234 --no-conda
```

I want output for my input but I got this message or error:

```
{'error_code': 'BAD_REQUEST', 'message': 'Encountered an unexpected error while evaluating the model. Verify that the serialized input Dataframe is compatible with the model for inference.', 'stack_trace': 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "C:\\Users\\subhash.kalicharan\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\pyfunc\\scoring_server\\__init__.py", line 276, in transformation\n    raw_predictions = model.predict(data)\n  File "C:\\Users\\subhash.kalicharan\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\pyfunc\\__init__.py", line 428, in predict\n    return self._predict_fn(data)\n  File "C:\\Users\\subhash.kalicharan\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\pytorch\\__init__.py", line 800, in predict\n    raise TypeError(\nTypeError: Expected PyTorch model to output a single output tensor, but got output of type \'<class \'transformers.modeling_outputs.TokenClassifierOutput\'>\'\n'}
```